# Keep OracleConnection alive

Tags: database, vb.net, oracle

I'm currently having an issue that has an open ticket with Oracle, but in the meantime I need to find a workaround.

I have a Windows Service developed in vb.net that is "listening" for incoming requests that go into an Oracle database queue. The problem that is now under investigation by Oracle is that after around 20 minutes of inactivity, i.e no new requests in the queue, the service apparently loses the ability to notice any new request that go into the queue. No matter how long I wait, nothing else will be detected by the service.

The solution that so far has solved the problem, is to have a task in Task Scheduler that triggers every 20min and restarts the service, which is clearly not ideal.

I was wondering if there was any way to implement in my code either a "keep-alive" order or a "ping" to the database to simulate some activity in the connection.

This is how I open the connection.

`oConn = New OracleConnection(connectionString)`

`oConn.Open()`

Can I do anything with this? I've looked into the OracleConnection class, but there doesn't seem to be anything useful for this situation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it will help, but - here you go.

As you mentioned a "ping", would TNSPING do any good?

```
C:\>tnsping xe

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 09-SIJ-2018 23:52:

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\Users\lf\Documents\E_0_library\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = lf.dat
CT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (10 msec)

C:\>
```

Or, if it doesn't keep the connection alive, maybe the *cheapest* option would be

```
SQL> select * from dual@xe;

D
-
X

SQL>
```

Those options are probably way too simple. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist way better.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was actually thinking into some kind of method or property to include in the code of my application, but if no one can guide me that way, I'll try to TNSPING the server from time to time.